# drawing text using CGContextShowTextAtPoint but text shown is inverted,

Tags: iphone

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingMacRoman);


    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 80, 80, "I am Rahul", 7);





 }
```

I am trying to draw text as shown above "I am Rahul" but when i execute the code,
text gets shown, but it is inverted, why it is happening I am not getting !! help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate text drawn by Quartz on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899775/how-to-rotate-text-drawn-by-quartz-on-iphone)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

Comment: user338322 you should really mark this as the answer as it works perfectly.

Comment: Just to add to this - the reason this works is because UIKit has a different coordinate system to CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 14):

This is easier:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSString* string = @"I am Rahul";
    [string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(80, 80)
               withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]];
}
```

Comment: [string drawAtPoint: withFont:] has been depricated by Apple. You now have to use [string drawAtPoint: withAttributes:]