# How do you change the color of a UIFont?

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont

I've searched the web and I can't get a good answer, although I'm sure this is very simple. Can someone please show me how to do the following: Make a UIFont of name "Helvetica-Bold", size 8.0, and color of black.

I've got the name and size, but I can't figure out how to change the color:

```
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:8.0];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

UIFont does not contain/maintain any color information, so this is not possible.  In general, controls that use UIFont such as a UILabel have both a font and a textColor property. So you would set a label's font and it's color like this:

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:8.0];
```

Comment: this functionality is removed from IOS 6.0

Comment: I think it works. I just did this in swift to get an alternating font colour for a UILabel:         
  commandCount += 1
  label.textColor = [.white, .black][commandCount % 2]

Answer (score 6):

If you are drawing text you can use following function;

```
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withAttributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:sizeOfFont], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor] }];
```

Answer (score 4):

If by any chance you're rendering the font to a texture in OpenGL, you can also use the [CGContext* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816659/drawing-text-using-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-but-text-shown-is-inverted),

Assuming you already have a valid cgcontext:

```
CGContextSelectFont(cgContext, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(cgContext, 1.0f, 1, 1, .5f) ;
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(cgContext, 20, 20, "HI THERE", strlen("HI THERE") ) ;
```

Comment: Note that CGContextSelectFont is deprecated now, use the CoreText API instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];`.

Comment: this functionality is removed from IOS 6.0