# Quartz 2D Text Drawing Errors in Encoding and Transformation?

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, cgcontext

I'm working on a Text Addition feature for my App. This text is going to be added with CGContext and Quartz 2D. The variable `text` is pulled from a UITextField's text property.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
CGRect textBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200);
UIView *textView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:textBox];
const char *textChar = [text UTF8String];   

NSInteger xLocation = (contentOffset.x + 100);
CGContextSelectFont (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), "Helvetica", 14.0f, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 255, 255, 255, 1.0); 
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xLocation, 110, textChar, 9);
[drawGallery addSubview:textView];
```

I have a few problems with this:

1. The text is rendering flipped - (this is easily rectified with a transform, but the tutorial I followed didn't have this issue so I'm confused a little [LINK](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_text/dq_text.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH213-TPXREF103)).
2. The text is rendering with strange characters - I think this is an encoding issue, but how do i adjust this?
3. The text doesn't get added to the view at the `addSubview` line, it only gets added when the CGContext is updated, i.e. I have a draw lines function too and if I draw on the view then the text magically pops up.
4. The text is horribly jagged and badly rendered, is there something I can do for this? I've added a `CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts` but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

See below for an example:

[image: strange characters]

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Did you use your text related CGContext* functions within drawRect method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text flipping, a solution to someone with the same problem was posted [text inverted problem solution [Stackoverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816659/drawing-text-using-cgcontextshowtextatpoint-but-text-shown-is-inverted/2819702#2819702) - use:

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
```

For the encoding problem, you are getting the text cString with `[text UTF8String]` (UTF8 characters are in general multibyte) but `CGContextSelectFont()` is specifying MacRoman (a single byte format).

Julian

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the bulk of these errors.

> 1. The text is rendering flipped
> 2. The text is rendering with strange characters - I think this is an
>      encoding issue, but how do i adjust
>      this?
> 3. The text doesn't get added to the view at the addSubview line, it only
>      gets added when the CGContext is
>      updated, i.e. I have a draw lines
>      function too and if I draw on the view
>      then the text magically pops up.
> 4. The text is horribly jagged and badly rendered, is there something I
>      can do for this? I've added a
>      CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts but it
>      doesn't seem to be doing anything.

1. Using a basic transformation, I was able to flip the text automatically.
2. Here I adjusted the encoding so MacRoman was used throughout.
3. I had to manually invoke an update - I wrote a function that does just that and called it where I needed it.
4. Due to the text print being caught in a loop, it appeared to print the text several times on top of each other, hence the jaggedness.