# CGContextShowText is rendering upside down text (mirror image)

Tags: ios, ipad, core-graphics

Without my doing anything to request upside down text, CGContextShowText is drawing it in that fashion. It is a mirror image vertically of what it should be.

```
float font_size = 19.;
CGContextSelectFont (context, "Helvetica", font_size, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (context, kCGTextFill); 
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor (context, 255, 0, 0, 0); 
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 255, 0, 0, 0); 
CGContextSetTextPosition (context, x, y);
CGContextShowText (context, cstring, strlen(cstring));
```

How can I fix this? Also why is this the default drawing mode?

Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer. One has to set the text matrix.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. (Also, I hope you're generating `cstring` from parts that will never contain characters in any other languages. Otherwise, this will draw garbage text in some locales.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate text drawn by Quartz on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899775/how-to-rotate-text-drawn-by-quartz-on-iphone)

Answer (score 8):

This "upsidedownness" commonly comes into play when the API renders to your cgContext from top to bottom, but somehow you're drawing from bottom to top.  Anyway, the 2 line solution I use is:

```
CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(tex->cgContext, trans);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    let textTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.textMatrix = textTransform
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is to simply call this at the beginning of your draw routine.  (Make sure to only call it once.)

```
    CGAffineTransform transform;
    transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGContextGetTextMatrix(ctx),
                                        CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                                              -1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, transform);
```